# Why can I connect to a local SQL Server Express but not to a remote SQL Server from PHP?

Tags: php, sql-server-2008, pdo, sql-server-express

This is the standard code when using windows authentication:

```
<?php
    try {
        $conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=geoffrey-pc\SQLEXPRESS;Database=books", 
                         NULL, NULL);
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo $e;
        die("Error connecting to SQL Server");
    }

    echo "Connected to SQL Server\n";
?>
```

The above works for connecting to the local server (SQL Server 2008 Express Edition), but not for connecting to a server on the network (SQL Server Standard Edition). The error message is:

> exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[28000]:
>   [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]Login failed for
>   user 'myDomain\GEOFFREY-PC$'.' in C:\wamp\www\PhpProject1\index.php:10
>   Stack trace: #0 C:\wamp\www\PhpProject1\index.php(10):
>   PDO->__construct('sqlsrv:Server=n...', NULL, NULL) #1 {main}

The connection string for the network server is the same as for the local server, except that the server name is similar to abc0120 and does not end with \SQLEXPRESS or anything else, and the database name is different. The database name I use with the network server does exist.

I am using Apache 2.2.11. The SQLServer 2005 MSDN page for [How to: Connect Using Windows Authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/cc296205%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx) reads:

> The credentials under which the Web server's process (or thread) is running must map to a valid SQL Server login in order to establish a connection.

Maybe that is the problem.

**I can connect to the network server using SQL Server Management Studio** also using windows authentication.

Comment: Put the connection string you use for the remote server in here.

Comment: @cularis, It is the same as the one for the localserver, except the server name is something like abc0120 (and does not end with \SQLEXPRESS) and the database name is different (and the database does exist).

Comment: Does the PHP process run under an account know to the SQL Server instance on the remote server? Typically, Management Studio runs under your own account, but the web server doesn't.

Comment: Does the remote SQL Server have tcp enabled?  By default network connections through to mssql 2005 are disabledL [link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/914277)

Comment: Can you echo out $e->getMessage() in the catch block and see what the actual error is?

Comment: @tdammers, the sqlsrv pdo uses Windows authentication by default.

Comment: @Gavin, I have edited the question to include the error message.

Comment: @Gavin, I am not sure if the TCP is enabled on the remore server. I have asked the owner to check.

Comment: I'm not sure about SQL server express but in other db server packages remote connects are disabled from default and user accounts are based on hostname/ip's as well unless set to '%'. This might be the same issue for you.

Comment: Do you use the same user to connect from Management Studio and from the web server?

Comment: Have you tried by any chance SQL Server Authentication via php script? Just to ensure there is no username typos.

Answer (score 2):

From the PHP manual, you have this example :

```
<?php
/* Connect to an ODBC database using driver invocation */
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=testdb;host=127.0.0.1';
$user = 'dbuser';
$password = 'dbpass';

try {
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

In your example, you omit the `$user` and `$password` arguments. I would try and specify a username and password instead of passing `null`; the user running your PHP script *might* not be the same as the logged user... omitting to provide a username and password, PHP tries to provide the user's credentials who's running the script (with perhaps even no password at all).

Comment: you are right. When the program is in production, the script should use SQL Server authentication instead of Windows authentication, so that all users of the script do not need to have permissions on the SQL Server.